# Generating and running a perl script from a bash script

Tags: bash, perl

I am trying to generate a perl script and run it from a bash script, but I am running into issues:

```
#!/bin/bash
str="perl"
array=( one two three )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   str=$str" -e 'print \"$i \";'"
done
echo "$str"
echo "AND THE PERL OUTPUT: "
$str
```

generates the output:

```
perl -e 'print "one ";' -e 'print "two ";' -e 'print "three ";'
AND THE PERL OUTPUT:
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

When I run the generated perl command `perl -e 'print "one ";' -e 'print "two ";' -e 'print "three ";'` manually, it works, but when I try to run it from the bash script, I get `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`

Cannot seem to figure out where I am missing the terminator

Comment: Use `set -x` to see exactly what's being executed

Comment: AHA! `exec -c perl -e ''\''print' '"one' '";'\''' -e ''\''print' '"two' '";'\''' -e ''\''print' '"three' '";'\'''`

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bash considers `'print` as a single unit, it has found a opening `'`, but failed to find a closing one (string terminator).

This is a safer version :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

str=(perl)
array=( one two three )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
   str+=(-e "print '$i ';")
done
echo "${str[@]}"
echo "AND THE PERL OUTPUT: "
"${str[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Rather than fighting with a variable and all the parsing nightmare that creates, write it to a file and source it.

```
$: cat tst
#!/bin/bash
tmp=$(mktemp)
array=( one two three )
{ printf "perl"
  printf " -e 'print \"%s \";'" "${array[@]}"
  echo
} >| $tmp

printf "the script:\n===\n"
cat $tmp
echo "AND THE PERL OUTPUT: "
. $tmp
rm $tmp

$: ./tst
the script:
===
perl -e 'print "one ";' -e 'print "two ";' -e 'print "three ";'
AND THE PERL OUTPUT:
one two three
```

But....why would you do this? =o]

Comment: If you're going to write it to a file anyway, wouldn't it make more sense to write the Perl script itself to a file, rather than writing a Bash command that *runs* the Perl script to a file?

Comment: this is just a test.. which is part of a larger bash file

Comment: @ruakh, hell yes, though sometimes it is admittedly easier to fold it all into one line if constructing programmatically. My thinking, on the other hand, is that if it complex enough to require Perl, it's time to rewrite the whole script in Perl.